# pythonの配列の[(),()]と[[],[]]の違いを教えて下さい。

Tags: python

unhashableのエラーがでます。
listData2で同じ結果にする方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

```
#(参考)配列の重複した内容を削除する方法!!＞多次元配列
#https://kiwamiden.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-contents-of-an-array
listData1 = [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
print(    list(set(listData1)))
print(len(list(set(listData1))))
# [(0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
# 2
listData2 = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
#print(    list(set(listData2)))
#print(len(list(set(listData2))))
#TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
listData1 = [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
```

これはタプルのリストです。

```
listData2 = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

これはリストのリストです。

リストは書き換え可能で、タプルは書き換え不可能です。

```
listData1 = [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1)]
print(    list(set(listData1)))
```

この場合、集合の要素はタプルです。

```
listData2 = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
print(    list(set(listData2)))
```

この場合、リストを要素とする集合を作ろうとします。
しかし、参考にしたページにあるように、また、

https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#set

> 集合の要素は ハッシュ可能 なものでなくてはなりません。

https://docs.python.jp/3/glossary.html#term-hashable

> ミュータブルなコンテナ (例えばリストや辞書) はハッシュ不可能です。

ともあるように、リストは集合の要素にすることはできません。タプルならできます。

一旦、タプルに変換してしまいましょう。

```
listData2 = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]

list_of_tuples = [ tuple(x) for x in listData2 ]    # タプルに変換
unique_list = list(set(list_of_tuples))             # 一旦集合にしてリストに戻す
list_of_list = [ list(x) for x in unique_list ]     # リストに戻す
print(list_of_list)
print(len(list_of_list))
```

Comment: ((),()))と([],[])と[(),()]と[[],[]]の4通りがある事がわかりました。